# Exchange string between c++ and C# with DLL

Tags: c#, c++, dll

I'm looking for exchange a string from my c++ code with my c# form.

Here is my code in my C# program:

```
[DllImport("libDLL.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
            public static extern string valeurExpr(IntPtr pImg);

            public unsafe string objetLibValeurCarteExpr()
            {
                return valeurExpr(ClPtr);
            }
```

And my code in my C++ program :

### Class IHM

```
 class IHM {
 private:
        std::string             card_number_str;
        std::string             card_expr_str;
        std::string             card_porteur_str;
```

### My extern

```
extern "C" _declspec(dllexport) std::string valeurExpr(IHM* pImg) {     return pImg->lireExpr(); }
```

### Function lireExpr()

```
 _declspec(dllexport) std::string lireExpr() const {
        return card_expr_str;
    }
```

When i execute Visual said that i try to access to a protected part of memory.

Comment: You can't (easily) marshal `std::string` objects across a managed boundary. `std::string` and `System::String` (as used by C#) are not interconvertible. A better solution would be to pass the string as a pointer to `char`, or to use the `BSTR` type in C++. Alternatively, you could write an interop layer in C++/CLI.

Comment: Is this of help : https://limbioliong.wordpress.com/2011/06/16/returning-strings-from-a-c-api/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all you cannot have `std::string` nor `std::wstring` in dll that you want to be accessible from other languages. So these fellows have to be changed to `char *` or `wchar_t *` <--- this is the real string - array of chars.

So, how to get string from C++ to C#?

C++

```
void foo(char *str, int len)
{
    //write here content of string
}
```

C#

```
[DllImport("...", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)
static extern void foo(StringBuilder str, int len);
```

and then you have to call it somehow:

```
void callFoo()
{
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(10); //allocate memory for string
  foo(sb, sb.Capacity);
}
```

Notice that in C# you have to use StringBuilder to get string from c++.

If you want to pass a string in the other way - from C# to C++ is simpler:
C++

```
void foo(const char *str)
{
    //do something with this str
}
```

C#

```
[DllImport("...", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)
static extern void foo(string str);
```

and then just:

```
void callFoo(string str)
{
   foo(str);
}
```

You have to remember about codepage. So if you're using unicodes, you will have to give additional attribute to DllImport: CharSet=CharSet.Unicode

Now classes. There is NO simple way to pass a class defined in C++ to C#. The simples way is to do some magic. So for every member function in C++ create non member function that will be exported to dll. Something like that:

```
//class in C++
class Foo 
{
public:
  int Bar();
};

//now you will have to define non member function to create an instance of this class:
Foo* Foo_Create() 
{ 
    return new Foo(); 
}

//and now you will have to create non member function that will call Bar() method from a object:
int Foo_Bar(Foo* pFoo) 
{ 
    return pFoo->Bar(); 
}

//in the end you will have to create a non member function to delete your object:
void Foo_Delete(Foo* pFoo) 
{ 
    delete pFoo; 
}
```

And then you can use it in C#:

```
[DllImport("Foo.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr Foo_Create();

[DllImport("Foo.dll")]
public static extern int Foo_Bar(IntPtr value);

[DllImport("Foo.dll")]
public static extern void Foo_Delete(IntPtr value);
```

You can also use a C# class in C++, but it's a little more complicated and requires use of C++/CLI

Comment: Hi ! Thank you for your help ! It is not me for the down vote... I try to implement this into my code, now i don't have any error (great !) but my string is empty. Any idea ?

Comment: Before trying to connect c++  and c#, i check my c++ code and my strings are ok.

Comment: OK, are you sure that you're using char * instead of std::string in C++? Are you sure, you're using StringBuilder instead of string in C#?